# Disable all except selected checkbox

Tags: jquery, html

I have to disable and enable three checkboxes.
if the user clicks on one the other will be disabled

```
<input type="checkbox" class="rambo" value='1' /> 45 
<input type="checkbox" class="rambo" value='2' /> 56 
<input type="checkbox" class="rambo" value='3' /> 56
```

so i need a function that gives me this via jquery

thanks for the advice

Comment: If you disable other checkboxes how will you check them again? You need to use radio button for this use case.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli by unchecking the first. At least, that's what I assumed in my answer below.

Comment: Why not use `<input type="radio">` instead of checkbox?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - OP mentioned just click and not check/uncheck so :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this sort of functionality, you should look into using [radio buttons](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm). These are best suited for mutually exclusive options compared to check boxes.

However, if you need to use check boxes, you could use the following:

```
$(function(){
    $(".rambo").change(function(){
        $(this).siblings().attr("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));  
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/qGbtQ/1/

---

And here is a solution which will uncheck all but the selected (like a radio button)

```
​$(function(){
    $(".rambo").change(function(){
       $(this).siblings().attr("checked", false);  
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/qGbtQ/

Comment: This is not what OP expected.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Which browser?

Comment: I meant as OP expected, when you click on any checkbox others should get disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".rambo").change(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    if ($el.is(":checked")) {
        $el.siblings().prop("disabled",true);
    }
    else {
        $el.siblings().prop("disabled",false);
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xUv9h/)

Comment: Just curious, why did you set $(this) to a new var?

Comment: To cache the `$(this)` object. Retrieving it from memory is much, much quicker than asking jQuery to create a new instance and wrap the object. Whenever you need more than one `$(this)` in a function, cache it.

Comment: Thanks Rory, I figured it'd be some kind of best practice that I wasn't aware of yet. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$('.rambo').click( function() {
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
        $(this).siblings().attr('disabled','disabled');   
    } else {
        $(this).siblings().removeAttr('disabled');   
    }
}​​);​
```

As you can see on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/jz8C5/2/)